# Why is Google Trend data inconsistent when downloaded on two different days?

Tags: google-trends

While working on a research project I noticed that when you download Google Trends data for the same keywords, time frame and location on two different days the values are changing. Has somebody also made the same experience before? Is there a reason behind?

Comment: I'm having the same problem - did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0):

The data is sampled nondeterministically, that's why the same request might yield different results.